# Jquery - background-image change with data attributes from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What do I have to change to get it working?

When I try to access `$(this).data("image")`, it is `undefined`.

HTML

```
<div id="imagecontainer"></div>
     <select class="image">
      <option data-image="url(http:www.test.de/images/test1.jpg)">Image1</option>
      <option data-image="url(http:www.test.de/images/test2.jpg)">Image2</option>
      <option data-image="url(http:www.test.de/images/test3.jpg)">Image3</option>
      <option data-image="url(http:www.test.de/images/test4.jpg)">Image4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.image').on('change', function() {
    $( "#imagecontainer" ).css( "background-image", ( $(this).data("image") ) );
})
```

Comment: You should first explain what you want working and what is currently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` element doesn't have a `data-image` attribute. The children `option` elements do, therefore you would have to select the selected option element:

```
$('option:selected', this).data("image");
```

or..

```
$(this).find('option:selected').data("image");
```

```
$('.image').on('change', function () {
    $("#imagecontainer").css("background-image", ($('option:selected', this).data("image")));
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/joe2ahed/)

Comment: Works. Thank you Josh!

Comment: how to avoid white flash?